# Flutter: upgrade android compiledSdkVersion

Tags: flutter

Going to android->app->build.gradle file, I see that my compiledSdkVersion is 27. But, actually, the latest one is 28. Should I have to upgrade to 28 or Flutter will take care of it with a future upgrade? And, if I have to take care about it, how can I?

Answer (score 2):

No `flutter upgrade` upgrades the Flutter SDK.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#upgrading-the-flutter-sdk-and-packages

If you want to upgrade the Flutter packages then
`flutter packages upgrade`

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#upgrading-packages-only

If you want you can manually change the version to 28 in your `build.gradle` file.